# Making for loop working in the background while loop

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop

So I confused at here

```
while self.voice_client.is_playing() == True:
   self.time += 1
    self.spot.clear()
```

```
for item in self.spot:
   video = search(query=item)
   self.query.append(video)
```

How to combine this two parts? I want that `for loop` is working same time as `while loop`. While `self.item += 1`, that `for item...` is running too

Comment: Can you explain what your code is doing. Are you trying to capture and record video?

Comment: I'm trying to play some music in discord.py @Kendle

Comment: You use threading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Making for loop working in the background while loop

Place the functionality of a `for` loop in the a `while` loop by programming the functionality of a `for` loop.

A `for` loop processes an iterable until the end of the items. The end of the items is identified by a `StopIteration` error which causes exiting from the `for` loop.

To replicate the functionality in code, make sure to ignore `StopIteration` and continue the outer loop.

```
# Build for loop functionality
self_spot = ['Song_1','Song_2']
self_spot_items = iter(self_spot) # The iterable part of a for loop

count = 0 #
while True:
    count += 1
    # For loop functionality
    try:
        print(f'{next(self_spot_items)=}')
        # video = search(query=item)
        # self.query.append(video)
    except StopIteration: # item processing done
        pass # continue the while loop
    # Outer loop functionlaity
    print(f'{count=}')
    if count > 10:
        break
```

Output

```
next(self_spot_items)='Song_1'
count=1
next(self_spot_items)='Song_2'
count=2
count=3
count=4
count=5
count=6
count=7
count=8
count=9
count=10
count=11
```